# capacitor placement: series or parallel with IC?

Tags: capacitor, integrated-circuit

I have doubts about capacitor placement near ICs, 
It's a good place for it?

----EDITED: IMAGES CHANGED TO SCHEMATIC -------------------------------

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: so, then don't use that drawing. Instead, draw a proper schematic. This website has a built-in schematic editor for that. I downvoted, because your cartoon of your circuit actually is more of a red herring than an illustration, considering your comment; I'll happily revert that vote once you've made a schematic that actually represents your problem. Also, I'm not convinced this is a good question: have you researched what a capacitor does *at all*? What happens to DC trying to pass through a capacitor?

Comment: Is the IC a fully integrated radio transmitter?  Or why is the output using a single wire and no reference?  // And what is the purpose of the capacitor?

Comment: I'm new in electronics, it's intended to conect with an Arduino (the blue wire goes to an input pin). You mean reference as ground? The IC is a hall sensor to detect a magnet.

Comment: Then I suggest Googling for "Hall sensor Arduino" to find similar projects, then see how they do it, copy that, profit.

Comment: The question is: capacitor must be in parallel or in series with IC's power/ground? I want to inderstand if IC has to receibe power "filtered" from capacitor or it's enough to put in parallel... Sorry, It may seem a stupid question but I'm novice in electronics :S

Comment: If the capacitor is in parallel with the power source, it shunt noise to ground.  A capacitor blocks DC, so what do you think will happen if you put one in series between the battery and the sensor?

Comment: I would suggest you learn basic electronics theory about voltage, current and capacitance.   And if all you need to do is to detect a magnet, you could use a reed switch.

Comment: Very much a novice. Draw your "series" circuit as a schematic diagram (instead of the wiring diagram you posted.) That should help you to see what is going on.  You may even find the answer yourself that way.

Comment: And, look up the datasheet and see how it shows the sensor being used.  Compare with any of the 3.14159265 gazillion comparable Arduino projects posted around the internet.

Comment: @user675319: Whatever program you have used to generate the wiring diagrams should be able to generate a circuit schematic. Replace what you've got with schematics.

Comment: You realise in your first diagram you have shorted the 5V and GND pins of the IC together?

Comment: @TomCarpenter I don't thin user675319 realizes, no. That's why we all insist that a schematic is drawn. We can't help anymore here. It's been 40 minutes and no schematic is posted, so I'm afraid that due to too many errors, too little own research and too little understanding  (OP's been told multiple times now that caps block DC, but that didn't seem to change anything), I'm voting to close this as "too broad". "unclear" would've worked, too, but I have to pick one close reason.

Comment: Edited, I replaced images with schematics.

Comment: I'm surprised about some people, I didn't know that ignorance is something to be punished. Just trying to learn, my apologies to everybody that was offended by my question.

Comment: We're by no means punishing your ignorance. We just try to bring you to do your part of the work (which *really* includes drawing a schematic!). Now, look at your schematic: it's really very novice, and I wished that you'd have used the built-in schematic editor, because it would make things easier to explain if the schematic was drawn with black, right-angled lines to illustrate what you're actually doing, but this is a huge step forward in helping you understand this! (as promised, I reverted my downvote, but you don't get an upvote: you really didn't produce a *proper* schematic, sorry)

Comment: So, what does in your first circuit, does PIN2 do? I don't see any reason for connecting a capacitor, unless a datasheet said the IC (which IC?) needs a specific external capacitor there. In any case, your schematic does NOT depict a decoupling cap. In your second schematic: as said multiple times now, research this question: **What does happen to DC trying to pass through a capacitor?** Notice that your batteries are a source of DC! So, I'm afraid neither of your circuits make sense!

Comment: The trouble now is that neither of your schematics match what the original breadboard pictures showed. And neither of them show how you would place a bypass capacitor.

Comment: My first schematic is confuse, I deleted. Also a comment that was relative to another image, now just Is an image. @Marcus Müller I'm reading about DC passing through capacitor, thanks for your comment.

Comment: pin 2 will go to arduino input. Power will come from arduino output, just simplified it to batteries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. OP's original circuit.*

The capacitor symbol indicates that it is made of two parallel plates with no contact between them. The capacitor can hold charge on the plates and can absorb some current while it charges up. In your arrangement it blocks battery power reaching the IC as DC cannot flow through it.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpxYUm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. The correct installation of the decoupling capacitor.*

The purpose of C1 is to act as a tiny battery right beside the chip. When the chip switches its output a very brief surge in demand can cause a momentary drop in voltage at the chip terminals due to resistance and inductance of the battery and wiring. The capacitor provides a tiny energy reservoir to supply the current during these momentary high demands. It can also absorb transients in the supply caused by other chips on the same power lines.

> I didn't know that ignorance is something to be punished.

You're not being punished. Read the comments from a neutral point of view. You've got a pile of guys trying to help within an hour of the post! If you can respond to the comments well - which I think you did - it's a great site.

Comment: Great explanation, just what I'm wondering. Thank you @Transistor and everyone, next time I'll work a little more in the post before publish it.

Answer (score 0):

The circuit is more like this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpB2XR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Given that the OP was confused about series or parallel connection of a decoupling capacitor I thing this is going to go over his/her head. You'll need to add a bit of explanation.